# Pro and con of publishing Azure test site before registering domain name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, publishing, web-publishing

I have been publishing my site to Azure and I've been restricting IP addresses so only people on my list can access the url ex. mysite.azuretestsite.com. But now I want to show people but I don't want to have to ask everyone for their IP address just to give them permission to view it.

The one thing I'm worried about is bots/web scrappers like Google who will pick up my site and then it might end up in their search results or for other purposes, which I don't want to happen before I go live.

Should I be worried about having the site live even though I have't registered the domain name yet? What are the pros and cons here and does it really matter if nobody know the site url? I'm more worried about bots/etc

Comment: Just create a dummy user in Azure AD, enable Authentication/Authorization in App Service and hand out the credentials. No code change necessary since the authentication wall is handled by the App Service layer before it hits your app code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, crawlers won't know your site `mysite.azurewebsites.net` exists, unless you have outbound link, and the landing website happens to turn on analytics.

For that case, there is nothing you can do about it. Otherwise, you have to ask user to sign-up before viewing your site.

Comment: when you say "outbound link" you mean a link on my site that go's to another site? ex. www.google.com

Comment: Yes, landing website could receive referred URL which is your Azure website.